# What is the "Spray Like" icon in the new MacBook Pro Touch Bar?

Tags: touch-bar

There is an icon that looks like a spray can on the right side of the Touch Bar (4th-5th button from the right?)

Does anyone know what it is for?

(Sorry I couldn't find an image of it on the web)

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the Touch Bar yourself by hitting ⌘+⇧+6 in 10.12.2 and add the picture to your question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems to be linked to the simulator in Xcode.

[image: the touchbar with spraycan]

When pressed this expands into some debugging shortcuts as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Expanded]

You can also see this icon on 9to5 macs article about the touchbar.
[9to5mac link](https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/04/macbook-pro-touch-bar-apple-apps-screenshot-gallery/)

Comment: I stared at it for a while, and I think... It's bug spray... debugging, get it? See also: https://twitter.com/martinlexow/status/1277939868849618945 https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/d5qhhh/the_icon_for_debugging_tools_on_the_touch_bar_is/ https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-is-the-perfume-button-on-my-macbook-pros-touch-bar.2029914/?post=24245149#post-24245149